# IIS / DirectoryEntry / ASP.NET - Logon Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory, iis-6

*Update*

Putting this at the top because it is crazy :)

So some users have it work, some don't.  When I use my own account via IE7 it doesn't work (my code catches the exception and falls back to simply using the identity name instead of the AD fullname).  When I try via Chrome it prompts me for the username and password, which I supply, and the fullname is displayed.  So the user account, server code and settings are identical, but using a different browser to send the authentication is making it work.

I also cleared all cookies from IE7, restarted, and there was no change in IE's behavior.  Plenty of users of IE7 are having it work fine.

*Update #2*

Remotely logged into a different machine, went to the page in IE7, and it shows my full name.  No clue.  I was thinking maybe session was caching something but I've republished the app and that should clear session.  I was thinking maybe a cookie had an old / bad token, but I've cleared those and tried again.  Something somewhere has to be getting long term caching.  Hopefully it works itself out.

*End Updates*

Hello,

I am retrieving a users full name from our AD in an ASP.NET (MVC) application running on IIS 6.0.

```
string domainUser = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();

DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + domainUser.Replace('\\', '/') + ",User");
filterContext.Controller.ViewData["User"] = (string)userEntry.Properties["fullname"].Value;
```

The last line throws an exception: "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

If I look at the HttpContext.User.Identity it is a valid Domain User and WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent is being impersonated properly.

This exception also seems to not be thrown 100% of the time, and it doesn't get thrown if browsed from the IIS Server.

My web.config looks like:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

What is bugging me is that if I remove the impersonation line:

```
WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();
```

It works.  The WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE which isn't a domain user but no exception is thrown and the fullname is retrieved from the AD.

The last bit is that this seems to have only started happening with a new deployment of the application (from test to live).  I don't know if I'm missing an IIS setting or what, but the code hasn't changed.

I know I've needed to impersonate previously to make it work, and it seems like I should need to impersonate, so I'm hesitant to remove the impersonation call without fully knowing what is going on and why this error is now happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the server hosting your ASP.NET application is not trusted for delegation.  Google for "trusted for delegation" for more info, or [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302400.aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: After testing a bit more, while I'm not sure where the problem is, I don't think it can 100% be the server.  I added an update, but basically it works for the same account, same server, same client machine, different browsers (one browser fails, one works).  I'm kind of stumped.  I did try the suggestion and set the server to be trusted for delegation, but things didn't seem to be fixed (that said, the time for propagation might be higher than I waited).